# Why does Redmine gives me error when exporting to pdf?

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am working on a project where we are using Redmine 5 (stable version) as our project management and issue tracking tool. It is a fresh Redmine installation with some additional plugins.

Yesterday, I have spotted that Redmine built in function to export pages (projects, wiki, etc.) to PDF does not work. When this function is triggered we get an application internal error.

[redmine installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NqDH.png)

[plugins installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WLIs.png)

I have checked the production logs but can not understand quite well what could be the problem.

Here is a link to the output from production.log.

```
`https://pastebin.com/v9y0hfiv`
```

Also, I have found out that error arises only when wiki pages have included images. If only text is present on wiki page, the export to PDF works. Therefore it must be something in relation images that are inserted to pages with text editor.

Can you please advise what could be the problem and how to solve it.

Thank you for your help.